# avoid executing other lines if my curl call fails for whatever reason

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have below lines in my script and it works fine as of now:

```
URL="$(hostname -f | grep -q "\.dev\." && echo "$URL_1" || echo "$URL_2")"
FILE="$(hostname -f | grep -q "\.dev\." && echo "file.init.proc" || echo "file.init.test")"
curl --fail -o "$TEMPFILE" "$URL" && if ! grep -q "$TEST_IPD" "$TEMPFILE"; then echo "ipaddress missing in the file" || return 2; else mv -- "$TEMPFILE" "$CONFIG_DIR/$FILE"; rm -f -- "$TEMPFILE"; fi
"line 4- something here"
"line 5- something here"
```

But earlier there was some problem in my `URL` and `FILE` line and because of which my `curl` line failed and for some reason still line 4 and line 5 got executed and I don't want those lines to be executed.

Let's say for some reason if I am not able to extract `URL` or `FILE` variable then if my curl line fails then I don't want line 4 and line 5 to be executed at all. Basically if my curl line fails for whatever reason I don't want line 4 or line 5 to be executed at all.

Comment: It looks like you already know how to use an `if` statement. What is the particular problem you're having?

Comment: problem is how to avoid executing line 4 and line 5. I thought `--fail` in `curl` will do exactly but it doesn't work or maybe it is working differently?

Answer (score 3):

Let's clean this up a bit.

```
if hostname -f | grep -qF '.dev.'; then
    URL=$URL_1
    FILE=file.init.proc
else
    URL=$URL_2
    FILE=file.init.test
fi

if curl --fail -o "$TEMPFILE" "$URL"; then
    if ! grep -q "$TEST_IPD" "$TEMPFILE"; then
        echo "ipaddress missing in the file" >&2
        return 2
    else
        mv -- "$TEMPFILE" "$CONFIG_DIR/$FILE" && rm -f -- "$TEMPFILE"
    fi
else
    "line 4- something here"
    "line 5- something here"
fi
```

`--fail` just causes `curl` to exit if something goes wrong; it has no effect on the shell that *executed* `curl`. Try to avoid using `&&` and `||` for anything other than short commands, and *never* use `... && ... || ...` in place of a proper `if` statement.

Comment: In my case `URL` and `FILE` is not a global variable so curl line will still works in your example?

Comment: BTW, it's safest to use lower- or mixed-case variable names (e.g. `url` instead of `URL`) to avoid conflicts with the various all-caps names with special meanings or functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to stop or continue after a failed command.
Here are some examples:

---

**Include the command as if condition** maybe the best way

```
$ if echo foo; then echo bar; fi  
foo  
bar
```

---

**Inspect the exit code** to know the result of a given command (the standard is to return a 0 exit code in case of success and a variable code from 1 to 255 in case of error) but as @Charles Duffy said

> this is an antipattern because it introduces complexity that wouldn't
>   exist if you didn't require the exit status to be recorded at all.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

```
$ echo foo  
$ echo $?  
0
```

So you can do something like:

```
$ echo foo  
foo
$ if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then echo bar; fi  
bar
```

---

**Using exit code and arithmetic mode**
*Testing for success*

```
$ if ! (($?)); then echo bar; fi  
bar
```

*Testing for failure*

```
$ if (($?)); then echo bar; fi
```

---

**Using `&&` `||`**

```
$ echo foo && echo bar || echo baz
foo  
bar
```

---

Speaking about your question, simplify and do something like this:

```
if curl -o "$TEMPFILE" "$URL"; then  
  echo SUCCESS   
  echo "Here's the logic of your 4 and 5 line or whatever you want."  
else  
  echo FAIL  
  echo "Maybe you should exit with an error code, like this "  
  exit 1  
fi  

exit 0
```

Comment: **Do not** encourage people to inspect `$?` manually -- `foo; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...` has no advantages whatsoever (and several disadvantages, including incompatibility with `set -e`, fragility when code is modified, reduced readability, etc) compared to `if foo; then ...`

Comment: See [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: In my opinio the best way is to include the command as if condition. I was doing a list of possibilities, I didn't know that using it was an antipattern! And yes you are right, it adds some complexity that can be avoided. Anyway thanks for writing it here so I can edit the answer to improve it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson sorry, I was wrong. I corrected the third example :) ty